# Terminating piped subprocesses in bash on ctrl+c

Tags: linux, bash

Let's say I have two text files such as a `file1.txt` and `file2.txt` which are aggregated to a single stream in a script that looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <( cat file1.txt | while read line; do sleep 1 && echo "first: $line" | tail -n +1; done & cat file2.txt | while read line; do sleep 1 && echo "second: $line" | tail -n +1; done)
```

If `ctrl+c` is pressed before the inner `cat` subprocesses are completed they are left running in the background when the script terminates. How can I modify this script so that all inner subprocesses (the two `cat` operations) are terminated when the script is closed with `ctrl+c`?

Edit: I don't want to use a loop if possible.

Comment: Each subprocess must have its own `trap` for `SIGINT` or you must test before and after the subprocess if it is called in a loop. Since `sleep` runs under its own PID, there isn't a way to interrupt `sleep` by sending `SIGINT` to the parent.

Comment: ...or use a `screen` session, which would kill all the processes within it.

Comment: I use bash4.3 and I'm unable to reproduce this. All the processes have the processes created by the above script on my PC have the same process group and so Ctrl-C targets them all. What version of bash are you using?

Comment: It's also working correctly with ksh and zsh.

Comment: I removed "sleep" (but I've now added it again) since I suspected that this was not the issue (but maybe it is?) The script I'm trying to fix is actually this one (https://github.com/johanhaleby/kubetail/blob/master/kubetail) and it doesn't use sleep and the inner subproccess is not actually cat but one that does indeed seem to generate its own pid. So maybe sleep is a good standin for this? If not please suggest how I can improve the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working by doing (comments are welcome):

```
#!/bin/bash
trap kill_subprocesses INT

PID=`echo $$`
tempfile="temp.${PID}"
touch ${tempfile}

function kill_subprocesses {
    while read p; do
        kill "$p" || kill -2 "$p" || kill -9 "$p"
    done < "$tempfile"
    rm ${tempfile}
}

cat <( cat file1.txt | while read line; do sleep 1 && echo "first: $line" | tail -n +1; done & echo $! >> ${tempfile}; cat file2.txt | while read line; do sleep 1 && echo "second: $line" | tail -n +1; done & echo $! >> ${tempfile};)
```

Comment: How about just `done <"$tempfile"`? and eliminate the *command substitution* with `echo` (and another subshell) in the process.

Comment: `kill` alone might not do it, you might need to to do something like `kill "$p" || kill -2 "$p" || kill -9 "$p"` to ensure the process is killed (assuming you want to try to kill it gently first) but more importantly you might be killing processes that aren't what you think they are - pid 17 might have been used for one of your processes which then died and then pid 17 got reused by the shell for some other process and then your script comes along and blows pid 17 away... Learn about quotes btw - `${p}` is doing nothing while `"$p"` is mandatory.

Comment: Good points Ed, thanks. Guess that this is not bullet-proof. Are there any options for dealing with the "reusability" problem?